# How to integrate Newton's law of cooling?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I have been given the differential equation $T'(t)=k(T(t)-A)$, where $T$=temperature, $t$=time, $A$=the constant temperature of the surroundings and $k$ is constant.

How do I find $T(t)$ expressed with $T_o$ = temperature when $t=0$,  $A$ and $k$.

It says to use the substitution with $u(t)=T(t)-A$.

Thanks :)

Comment: Welcome to Math SX. We expect a little more effort from you. Use that substitution. Note that $u'(t)=T'(t)$. Can you solve $u'(t)=ku(t)$?

Comment: This is an old question, why am I seeing it now?

Answer (score 1):

1. First way, use Laplace transform:
   $$\text{T}'\left(t\right)=\text{K}\cdot\left(\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}\right)\to\text{s}\cdot\text{T}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{T}\left(0\right)=\text{K}\cdot\left(\text{T}\left(\text{s}\right)-\text{A}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}\right)$$

Solving $\text{T}\left(\text{s}\right)$:

$$\text{T}\left(\text{s}\right)=\frac{\text{T}\left(0\right)-\text{K}\cdot\text{A}\cdot\frac{1}{\text{s}}}{\text{s}-\text{K}}$$

Now, using inverse Laplace transform:

$$\text{T}\left(t\right)=\text{A}+e^{\text{K}t}\left(\text{T}\left(0\right)-\text{A}\right)$$

Setting $\text{T}\left(0\right)=\text{T}_0$, we get:

$$\color{red}{\text{T}\left(t\right)=\text{A}+e^{\text{K}t}\left(\text{T}_0-\text{A}\right)}$$

2. Second way (solving the separable equation):

$$\text{T}'\left(t\right)=\text{K}\cdot\left(\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}\right)\Longleftrightarrow\int\frac{\text{T}'\left(t\right)}{\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}}\space\text{d}t=\int\text{K}\space\text{d}t$$

Use:

- Substitute $u=\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}$ and $\text{d}u=\text{T}'\left(t\right)\space\text{d}t$:
  $$\int\frac{\text{T}'\left(t\right)}{\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}}\space\text{d}t=\int\frac{1}{u}\space\text{d}u=\ln\left|u\right|+\text{C}=\ln\left|\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}\right|+\text{C}$$
- $$\int\text{K}\space\text{d}t=\text{K}\cdot\int1\space\text{d}t=\text{K}\cdot t+\text{C}$$

So, we get:

$$\ln\left|\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}\right|=\text{K}\cdot t+\text{C}$$

Solving $\text{C}$, use $\text{T}\left(0\right)=\text{T}_0$:

$$\ln\left|\text{T}_0-\text{A}\right|=\text{K}\cdot 0+\text{C}\Longleftrightarrow\text{C}=\ln\left|\text{T}_0-\text{A}\right|$$

So, we get:

$$\color{red}{\ln\left|\text{T}\left(t\right)-\text{A}\right|=\text{K}\cdot t+\ln\left|\text{T}_0-\text{A}\right|}$$

Answer (score 1):

We have $T'(t)=k(T(t)-A)$.

Using the substitution $u(t)=T(t)-A$, we get $u'(t)=T'(t)$.

Then, we have $u'(t)=ku(t)$.

Rearranging, we have $\displaystyle 
\frac{u'(t)}{u(t)}=k$.

Integrating both sides with respect to $t$, gives us $\ln|u(t)|=kt+C$.

We then have $|u(t)|=e^Ce^{kt}$, which gives $u(t)=ce^{kt}$.

Finally, we substitute back in to get $T(t)-A=ce^{kt}$, so that $\boxed{T(t)=A+ce^{kt}}$.

---

I used the function notation, so for the most part I ignored differentials like $du$ and $dt$, but the method is clear.